# Running JUnit tests against more type of databases

Tags: java, database, testing, junit, spock

I have an application that uses databases through jdbc API (in fact spring jdbc template). We want to run our unit tests against more type of databases (MS SQL, Oracle, Postgre); 
Thus to run a test (for example with maven) that will run a unit tests 3x times, for each specified databases.

How to elegantly solve this?

(I was thinking in a own implementation of JUnit runner, but we have also Spock tests)

Comment: How do you manage the database today?

Comment: Currently we are just testing against one database, since the queries are quite simple, we try to write standard SQL queries; We are in early stage so we just changed the configs for databse connections manually to do tests on other databases than H2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental question is how to run the same test multiple times with different DB settings. You could either implement this at the test framework level (e.g. with a custom JUnit runner or as a DBUnit/[Unitils](http://unitils.org) extension) or at the build tool level (if your build tool is flexible enough). In both cases it should be possible to have one implementation that works with JUnit and Spock. (By the way, Spock provides Unitils integration out-of-the-box).

Comment: It's supposed to be an answer.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, but this is quite obvious, also Mark denoted it;(JUnit runner) also yes for example with maven the running of the tests could be altered. But these solution are rather tricky than an "elegant" solutions, I think....but thx...

Answer (score 5):

Start with  [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)

> DbUnit is a JUnit extension (also usable with Ant) targeted at database-driven projects that, among other things, puts your database into a known state between test runs. This is an excellent way to avoid the myriad of problems that can occur when one test case corrupts the database and causes subsequent tests to fail or exacerbate the damage.

Use a separate JdbcDatabaseTester for each database - the unit tests etc should be coded to IDatabaseTester and so can run with all the databases.

Comment: Hi, I don't used this framework for now, now I checked it quickly. But I don't really understand how do you mean this. So I should crate a JdbcDatabaseTester for each database, but how to use them in one test, thus how it will execute my test cases 3 times (for all my database connections?!).

Comment: You would have to create a new top level driver that would run each suite with each JdbcDatabaseTester

Comment: Yeah, thats was my first intention with JUnit, do you think its is easier with DbUnit, what is the base top level driver class?

Comment: @Mark : any example github code for DBunit application?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you testing? Your java code operating JDBC? Your sql statements against database schema?  Depending on the answer, there are 2 strategies:

In case it is java code you are testing,  just mock up JDBC connection with  mocking framework of your choice ( I would recommend jMockit ) and see that your code issues proper 
sql statements

In case it is database schema you can prepare SQL statements and send them to DB of your choice  by most convenient means ( DBUnit could be also used for this purpose, or SoapUI, 
or other DB management tool )

Separating those 2 concerns would provide simpler and more robust tests for each tier.

PS: also consider to use some form of ORM - like JPA

Comment: We want to do integration tests like this, so both.

Comment: I'm not sure whether jUnit is the right too for integration test. MOst certainly not.  I would put something like jMeter or SoapUI in this context